# Unable to call the function, to test HTML Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mocha.js

I need to test HTML events in Mocha, I've the following code in Event.html file

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Html Attributes testing</title>
    <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css" />


    <!-- Include JS File Here -->


     <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

     <script src="test-lib/chai.js"></script>

     <script src="test-lib/mocha.js"></script>

     <script> mocha.setup('bdd');</script>

     <script src="Test.js"></script>

     <script src="Application.js"></script>

        <script>
             window.onload = function() {
             mocha.run()
        };

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <p>This example uses Triggers to "click" event.</p>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").trigger("click");
    });
    </script>


    <p id="demo" onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);">Click me.</p>


    </body>
    </html>

And the following code in Application.js file 

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";

    }

And the following code in Test.js file

var expect = chai.expect;


describe('EventTesting', function() {
  it('Testing Events in JavaScript', function(done) {

  var v1 = myFunction();
  expect(v1).to.equal("YOU CLICKED ME!");
  done();

    });
});
```

In Application.js file, i called `"<p id="demo">"` attribute using `document.getElementById("demo")` and set value as `YOU CLICKED ME!` and i click it using "triggers".

```
In Test.js file i want  to call that function which is reside inside "Application.js" file and need  to check whether its value is "YOU CLICKED ME!" and I want my testcase to be passed.
```

But i got the following error: "AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'YOU CLICKED ME!'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not self-duplicate your questions. If you have made progress with a problem that you already asked on SO, then edit the question you already posted. If this question is really a different one, then you have to make clear how it is different from your earlier question.

Answer (score 0):

This is virtually a carbon copy of [the last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996723/unable-to-identify-whether-my-test-case-pass-or-fail). The answer is the same:

your variable v1 is set to the return value of the function *myFunction()*, but *myFunction()* doesn't return anything. So when you try to compare v1 (whose value will be unset, i.e., 'undefined') to "YOU CLICKED ME!", you get that error.

I'm not going to repeat everything that's incorrect in the code above, you've changed barely anything about it since the last time. For a full list of everything yu need to change, see my answer to your last question in the link above.